# How to add method to existing class in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, class, object, methods

I have this really convenient high-level `pd.DataFrame` saving function that I want to add to `pandas`.  How can I add this method to the `pd.DataFrame` class?

```
def to_file(df, path, sep="\t", compression="infer", pickled="infer", verbose=False, **args):
    _ , ext = os.path.splitext(path)
    # Serialization
    if pickled == "infer":
        if ext in {".pkl", ".pgz", ".pbz2"}:
            pickled = True
        else:
            pickled = False
    # Compression
    if compression == "infer":
        if pickled:
            if ext == ".pkl":
                compression = None
            if ext == ".pgz":
                compression = "gzip"
            if ext == ".pbz2":
                compression = "bz2"
        else:
            compression = None
            if path.endswith(".gz"):
                compression = "gzip"
            if path.endswith(".bz2"):
                compression = "bz2"
    if verbose:
        print(
            f"path:\t{path}", 
            f"sep:\t{repr(sep)}",
            f"compression:\t{compression}",
            f"pickled:\t{pickled}", 
            sep="\n", 
            file=sys.stderr,
        )
    if pickled == False:
        df.to_csv(path, sep=sep, compression=compression, **args)
    if pickled == True:
        df.to_pickle(path, compression=compression, **args)
```

Comment: maybe a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance

Comment: no its not he wants to add to the class not to an instance of the class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use python class inheritance. This will allow you to use all the methods in a Pandas data frame and still define your own methods.

```
import pandas as pd

class NewDF(pd.DataFrame)
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pd.DataFrame.__init__(self, *args)

    def to_file(df, path, sep="\t", compression="infer", pickled="infer", verbose=False, **args):
        ...
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.to_file = to_file` also works but I like the above approach.  Thanks, this will come in handy for other things.